# How to use Route element as a variable/reference in react-router-dom 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Let's say we have a component `Home.jsx`

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

and our router goes as

```
const Router = () => (
  <>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  </>
);
```

**That's works fine!** But what if we want to import the `element` as below in the `Route` component

**views.js**

```
export { default as Home } from "./home";
```

and modify our routes as follows

```
import * as views from "../views";

<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={views.Home} />
 </Routes>
```

this piece of code makes following error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

What's the way out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I come up with a workaround, and that is use variable as method.
Here it is:

```
  <Route path="/" element={views.Home()} />
```

Comment: Why not `<Route path="/" element={<views.Home />} />` ?